# Pantheon SFTP config parameters for Remote - SSH vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh, pantheon

What .ssh config file parameters are needed to connect Remote - SSH extension at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh&ssr=false#version-history to Pantheon hosting?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pantheon does not allow customers SSH access and the VS Code Remote SSH extension [does not support SFTP/FTP](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_can-i-use-vs-code-when-i-only-have-sftpftp-filesystem-access-to-my-remote-host-no-shell-access).

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use the Remote SSH extension on Pantheon for SFTP.

It might be possible using a [different extension](https://evolvingweb.com/drupal-development-using-visual-studio-code-and-pantheon), but I have not tested this.